# The following is not increment the file count correctly Any Clue as to why?

Tags: powershell

This powershell code searches the directory and outputs a list of all the files and how old they are to a log file that is parsed buy a different script. all that is working correctly but i also need to keep track of the number of files it found for that dir and the number of files found globally. Thats what the two foreach-Object statements do. but they are staying at 0.

```
 gci -filter *.avi | Select-Object Name, @{Name="Age"; Expression= { (((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days) }} | Where {$_.Age -ge $daysToKeep} | Out-File -filepath $logFile -append | Foreach-Object {$fileCountCam1++} | Foreach-Object {$fileCount++}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out-File is a termnating cmdlet (it doesn't ouput the object to the pipeline), so everything after it isn't getting any input from the pipeline.

See if this works better:

```
gci -filter *.avi |
Select-Object Name,  @{Name="Age"; Expression= { (((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days) }} |
 Where {$_.Age -ge $daysToKeep} | 
 Foreach-Object {
                 $_ | Out-File -filepath $logFile -append
                 $fileCountCam1++ 
                 $fileCount++
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

mjolinor's solution is valid, but there's another way (if you can use v3). You can use [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) to write to the file without a loop.

You can also combine your two variable increments into the same script block in the final `foreach-object` which will speed things up significantly.

```
gci -filter *.avi |
    Select-Object Name, @{Name="Age"; Expression= { (((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days) }} |
    Where {$_.Age -ge $daysToKeep} | Tee-Object -filepath $logFile -append |
    Foreach-Object {$fileCountCam1++;$fileCount++}
```

Comment: Might want to note that the ability to append using tee-object requires V3 or better.